# Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

Tags: nodejs, express, ejs, babel

Obtengo

> "Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided."

al hacer `res.render("index", { email: verify.email })` dentro de una funcion para resetear password. Estoy usando la extensión **babel** y tengo la sensación de que el problema esta ahí.

```
import User from "../models/User.js";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import "dotenv/config";
import express from "express"
const app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


export const resetPassword = async (req, res) => {
  const { id, token } = req.params;
  console.log(req.params);
  const oldUser = await User.findOne({ _id: id });
  if (!oldUser) {
    return res.json("User does not exist");
  }
  const secret = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET + oldUser.password;
  try {
    const verify = jwt.verify(token, secret)
    res.render("index", { email: verify.email })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.send("Not verified")
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

estás renderizando un archivo llamado index, pero express no sabe la extensión, tienes que poner un setting que lo haga, por ejemplo si tu motor de plantillas es ejs:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

O si es un html podrías hacerlo así:

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html', {email: verify.email}));.
```

No olvides requerir el módulo **"path"** de node